What excel formula can I use to compare 2 columns and pick the cell that does not have #n/a in it?




A
B
C




**1**
ID 1
ID 2
Expected Output


**2**
0011Q00001xC8a7QAC
#N/A
0011Q00001xC8a7QAC


**3**
0011Q00001xC8aTQAS
#N/A
0011Q00001xC8aTQAS


**4**
#N/A
0011Q00001xxxFFFQr
0011Q00001xxxFFFQr


**5**
#N/A
0011Q00001xxxFFFQz
0011Q00001xxxFFFQz



With given data in column A and B I'm trying to get the value from column A or B in case it's not #N/A.
I tried using IF, IFS, etc but couldn't find a way to write it in a way it produces expected result.
By the way, I can replace '#n/a' by any value if it's causing an issue with the formula. thanks!

is the #N/A the error or a string value?

If you only ever have one instance of #N/A in a row, then =IFNA(A2,B2)

or, if there is always one good value and one error then: =TOCOL(A2:B100,3) to spill.

If there is always one "good" answer and one Error per line then use:
=TOCOL(A2:B100,3)

It will spill the results:

